# In a Batch file, how do I get the folder name, instead of the entire directory?

Tags: batch-file, directory, 7zip

I have a batch file that I use to 7zip files with specific settings, that automatically reduces the settings if the PC runs out of memory or fails for some reason. I drag a folder onto the batch file, and it will create an archive, in the root directory of the folder being 7zipped.

eg: Folder to compress `Z:\Test\Example Folder`. If I use this code:

```bash
for %%x in (%*) do (
Rem //  Use Current Argument To set File, Folder, and Archive Paths
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="%%~x.7z"
```

I end up with a 7zip file in the root directory of the folder being compressed, e.g. `Z:\Test\Example Folder.7z`

If I use this code:

```bash
for %%x in (%*) do (
Rem //  Use Current Argument To set File, Folder, and Archive Paths
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\NEW.7z"
```

I end up with a 7zip file, `C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\NEW.7z`

I have tried amending `C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\%%~x.7z`, but it just fails. I presume because `%%~x` actually means `Z:\Test\Example Folder` and not just `Example Folder`

What code do I need to use to have the 7zip file end up:
`C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\Example Folder.7z`

The main reason for this change in the code, is because sometimes I need to 7zip folders on the network, and it's too slow and sometimes fails, writing to the network drive at the same time. I'd like to be able to set a default folder and get a speed benefit when using 7zip across different drives.

Comment: `if errorlevel n` means "If the errorlevel is n `or greater than n`". Hence, you need to examine `errorlevel` in reverse-order. Also, if you execute any of the branches that depend on `errorlevel`, `errorlevel` will become be set by the last command in that branch to set it, ie.the `7z` step.

Comment: The code you're referring to has been removed as it wasn't on topic.

Answer (score -1):

The code specifically required is `%%~nx`. This grabs the folder name and allows it to be used to move the default archive location.

For example, to compress `Z:\Test\Example Folder` and have the file stored in `C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed`

```bash
    Set archivePath="C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\%%~nx.7z"
```

If it is plugged into the original code:

```bash
     for %%x in (%*) do (
Rem //  Use Current Argument To Set File, Folder, and Archive Paths
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\%%~nx.7z"
```

Files are correctly placed in the compressed folder with the original folder name: `C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\Example Folder.7z`

Instead of using `for` it would be better to use `:LoopStart`, and the method for defining the 7z file name in this case will be `%~n1`.

Eg:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "archivePath=C:\Users\Dr4gon\Downloads\Compressed\%~n1.7z"
set /a count=0
:LoopStart
set /a count+=1
if %count% gtr 4 goto EndLoop
if %count%==1 (
  set successThread=3
  set successDictionary=2048m
) else if %count%==2 (
  set successThread=5
  set successDictionary=1024m
) else if %count%==3 (
  set successThread=8
  set successDictionary=256m
) else if %count%==4 (
  set successThread=6
  set successDictionary=96m
)
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -aoa -t7z -mx9 -m0=LZMA2 -md=!successDictionary! -mfb273 -mmt=!successThread! -v1073741824 "!archivePath!" "%~1\*"
pause
exit
```

This will enable you to set the location of the output 7z file to the location of your choosing. If you wanted to make it a choice, add something like:

```bash
:input
cls
set "response="
choice /M "Should the 7z file be placed into the current directory?" /C YN
if errorlevel 2 goto No
if errorlevel 1 goto Yes
:Yes
set "archivePath=%~n1.7z"
goto :Loop
:No
set "archivePath=C:\Users\D4rgon\Downloads\Compressed\%~n1.7z"
goto :Loop
:Loop
```

This can enable you to choose based on the situation. But warning, this will not compress individual files, only folders, and in limited testing some special characters will work, but others may cause issues; for example, `!` in the folder name, will cause a failure.